# Count lines found with find command

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find

I have configured glusterfs into two servers.

I want to implement a script wich monitors the replication. My idea is to exec the following:

```
find "/replica_path/" -mmin +1 -exec ls -l {} \; |wc -l
```

This will find the files modified more than 1 min ago and must return the same count in both servers.

I'll use spawn to exec this line remotely-

But when executing that line from the command line, the server takes a long to return the path, in fact I've to break the execution.

How could I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls -l` might need quite some time to resolve owner names etc.

perhaps you just need to count the number of matches:

```
find "/replica_path/" -mmin +1 | wc -l
```

Comment: Few secs before and I answer the same line, thank you very much, I thought I've to include -exec flag into find command but I realize not.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to avoid executing /bin/ls for each matched item if you just want to count them.

Try

```
find "/replica_path/" -mmin -1 -print | wc -l
```

Comment: thank you very much, I was looking for files modified 1 min ago or more, that will give me the one modified 1 min ago or less.